# Passing HTML Attributes through to JQuery Post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, facebook-like

I'm trying create a "Like" option on my websites topics and I want to pass data through an a tag to php using JQuery post but it isn't working properly.  Here is the code that I have:

```
<a class="likelink" href="#" poster="$yourid" like="$postid" user="$postusername">Like</a>

$('.likelink').on('click', function()
            {
            var poster = $(this).attr("poster");
            var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
            var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
            var like = $(this).attr("like");
            var user = $(this).attr("user");
            {
                jQuery.post("php/like.php", {
                poster:poster,
                like:like,
                user:user
                },  function(data, textStatus){
                if(data == 1){
                $('.likethis').html("Success");
                }else{
                $('.likethis').html("Error");
                }
                });
            }
            return false;
            });
```

Can anyone see if there are any possible errors here or if there is a better solution. Thanks

Comment: it looks pretty standard.  What error are you getting?  Are you getting a PHP error?  A JavaScript error?

Comment: also use `data- attributes`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors at all, the link just isn't sending the information to the php file from what I can tell as nothing is going into the database.

Comment: The first thing to do is use a tool like Firebug.  Look at the console.  Look at the network tab.  See if the function is being called at all and what data is being transferred over.  One thing I did see if that you don't need the curly braces before the jQuery.post line.

Comment: Thanks Brian, it's because I was using the script from a previous function and haven't edited it yet.  I've added firebug and it's not showing anything on the errors, It's like the function doesn't exist?

Comment: Well, the code you pasted in is working correctly in jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QmtXC/ .... so.. what values do you have in the anchor tag?  Also, do you run the code after the document has been loaded?  What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: The values are just what's been selected using php, so for example $yourid & $postid would = something like 123456789-8585 and $username would be username123

Comment: It looks like you need to prevent the hyperlink to act as a hyperlink in this case. Did you try using `e.preventDefault()` ? More information can be found here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do when you call `return false` ? `ajax` is `asynchronous`, this function will `return false` before the `ajax` result come back.

Comment: Thanks @BrianHoover, the code was being loaded before the document was loaded. I've fixed it now and the script is running but the variables aren't being passed to the external php script for some reason. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Could you send a link to the code or paste your HTML into jsFiddle? It doesn't need to post to anything valid, just run.

Comment: @BrianHoover I fixed the problem! What had happened was that I was originally sending the information through an <a href> tag so the php file was using $_get, so now I've changed it to `$poster = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["poster"]);` and everything works.  Thanks for all the help though